# a parabola and a branch of hyperbola tangent at 2 points

Tags: geometry, asymptotics, conic-sections

Is following true?

> If a parabola and a branch of hyperbola are tangent at 2 points and on the same side of the common tangents, then the hyperbola is "outside" the parabola.

Example:
[image: 抛物线与双曲线内切于2点, 则抛物线在内侧]

To generalize, two conics with $e\ge1$ are tangent at 2 points and on the same side of the common tangents, then the one with greater eccentricity lies on the "outside". ([here](http://kuing.infinityfreeapp.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=10729) is my calculation for a right hyperbola and a hyperbola)

Comment: Yes; a hyperbola has two asymptotes, so its end behavior mimics that of a line and does approach infinity. However, that of a parabola (in this case x = y^2) approaches infinity much quicker because of the rate of growth of a squared term. So, the parabola must be "inside" the hyperbola. If it was the other way around, the parabola would intersect the hyperbola as it gets steeper. This is more intuitive, not an actual proof or anything of course.

Comment: How to express it in more precise language? Asymptotics?

Comment: It is not true, in that an ellipse can go inside a circle and be tangent at two points, and the circle can fit inside the ellipse, too.  Add the condition that $e\ge 1.$

Comment: @user317176 Thanks, I added $e\ge1$.